# TNS 12545, 00511. Oracle not start

Tags: oracle-10g

I have a Linux server that has oracle 10g release 10.1.0.3.0 and NMS software. I need to change its IP address and default gateway. So:
1- While oracle and NMS are started I change IP and default gateway addresses just in Linux YAST, suddenly NMS got faulty,
2- To solve the faulty condition quickly I change back the setting to its original state by Linux YAST, remember that I change the IP setting in YAST when oracle is up, is it harmful? Must I change the setting when oracle is down? On the other hand, I change them back but not sense.
3- To get ride of the situation I shut down the NMS application and oracle,
4- Then I decided to start oracle again, but until now it can not be started. I tried some times, but no result. Reboot the Linux server then start oracle, again no success.

Here is the content of the oracle restart process report:

- You must be an ‘oracle’ Unix user to restart the oracle platform
- Pass:
- SQL*plus : Release 10.1.0.3.0 production on Jun 3 13:23:36 2021
- Copy right(c) 1982, 2004, oracle.all rights reserved
- SQL> connected
- SQL> Database closed
- Database dismounted
- ORACLe instance shutdown
- SQL> Disconnected from oracle Database 10g Release 10.1.0.3.0 Production
- Database “ NMS5UX” shutdown
  -LSNRCTL for Linux: version 10.1.0.3.0 production on 03-Jun-2021 13:24:25
- Copyright(c) 1991, 2004, oracle, All rights reserved -Connecting to (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PEOTOCOL= (IPC)(KEY= EXPORT)))
- TNS-12541: TNS: no listener
- TNS-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
- TNS-00511: No listener
- Linux Error:2:No such file or directory
- connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TPC)(HOST=nms5lxgr) (PORT=1522)))
- TNS-12545: Connection failed because target host or object not exist
- TNS-12560:TNS:Protocol adapter error
- TNS-00511: Connection failed because target host or object does not exist
- SQL*PLUS:Release 10.1.0.3.0 production on Thu Jun 3 13:24:25 2021
- Copyright(c) 1992, 2004, oracle, All rights reserved
- SQL> Connected to an idle instance
- SQL> ORACLE INSTANCE STARTED
- Total System Global Area 536870912 bytes
- Fixed-size 779976 bytes
- Variable size 274995512 bytes
- Database Buffers 260046648 bytes
- Redo Buffers 1048576 bytes
- Database mounted
- RUNNING ora-lgwr-NMS5UX
- RUNNING ora-pmon-NMS5UX
- RUNNING ora-reco-NMS5UX
- RUNNING ora-smon-NMS5ux
- RUNNING ora-dbwo-NMS5UX
- RUNNING ora-ckpt-NMS5UX
- NOT RUNNING tnslsnr
- Oracle process check FAILED
- Press enter key to continue

By reading the report it seems that refer to errors  TNS-12545 and TNS-00515 it lost the host. But refer to connection by PROTOCOL = TCP, HOST is introduced by name and I didn't change the server name at all.
I just worked on network settings, and I put them back to the original settings. At the end of the report, it is mentioned that tnslsnr is not running and the oracle process check failed.

I checked the .ora text files, they contain ‘HOST’ with the server name, not the server IP. I conclude that address to name resolution is done in /etc/hosts file that I didn't change at all.

Please:
1- How I can solve this fault and start-up oracle?
2-  Is it necessary to change the network setting when oracle is down?

I appreciate any advises.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Could you please try and format your question properly, using code tags for commands and their output? It's really hard to read in its current form.

Comment: I tried to add the pictures of oracle startup in 2 situations to compare them: first 2 photos belong to successfull oracle start up condition, and next two photos belong to FAILED oracle startup.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you break a system by changing things, reverting them and sometimes restarting the software helps.
Most important is that you know about the architecture and design decisions. That can help solving and even prevent problems.
The listener is a process that listens to client requests. It helps if it is in a network that can be reached by the clients. The databases it serves are normally on local host.

To me it looks like the database is running. For some reason, the listener is not. Run “lsnrctl start” as the oracle Linux user to get it started.

Btw: running on 10.1 is not what we often see these days. For me that means that the application has no importance at all. Otherwise it would have been maintained.

Comment: Thanks ik_zelf, i revert things but no result. For restart what do you mean? I restart linux with no result. Any other restart you know? You mean oracle restart? How is it?

Comment: Check your scripting and find why your listener is not started.

Comment: It send error report TNS 00515 that for tcp connection , the host or object is not exist. Af. I checked listener.ora file. There i mention HOST with  hostname and i just set and reset ip address not host name.

Comment: After precise check i found that the /etc/hosts file content is strange, based on it my server ip address is OK but its hostname is different from hostname that set in YAST.  So it could be predicted that name resolution that done in listener could not been done, so certainly its because of that.

Comment: So the root cause is detected, But how can i solve it. How /etc/hosts file will be loaded, manually or by YAST ؟.

Comment: Final it had been solved. I changed the ip using YAST in suse, and pay attention to file /etc/hosts, to have accepted content, all the things go well,

Comment: Thanks to all for their attentions and advises.